# How to pronounce $\sim$ and $\overline a$ in equivalence relations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question

I just was thinking about the basic statement shown below relating equivalence relations and partitions. My question specifically is, how to pronounce this statement,
$$
\overline a = \{x \in S: x \sim a \}.
$$
Would it be correct to pronounce it as "the cell containing $a$ is defined as the set of all $x$ in $S$ such that $x$ is equivalent to a?" Is this correct pronunciation of $\overline a$ and $\sim$? As one of my math professors pronounces $\sim$ as "twiddle," the statement then might sound like, "the cell containing $a$ is defined as the set of all $x$ in $S$ such that $x$ twiddles a." Is that correct?

---

Let $S$ be a nonempty set and let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $S$. Then $\sim$ yields a partition of $S$, where
$$
\overline a = \{x \in S: x \sim a \}.
$$
Also, each partition of $S$ gives rise to an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $S$ where $a\sim b$ iff $a$ and $b$ are in the same cell of the partition.

Comment: Never heard to term "cell" used that way. The "class of $a$" of "the equivalence class of $a$" is $\bar a$. The term "equivalent to" is a bit overloaded, so you might prefer to just say "$a$ tilde $b$" or "$a$ twiddle $b$," just to indicate it is an unknown relationship.

Comment: I have sometimes heard $a \sim b$ read aloud as "a equiv b".

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you. I got confused about the use of the word cell; just realized I saw it used in a textbook to refer to a "cell" of a partition, versus an "equivalence class" of an equivalence relation. Although the term "cell" is unnecessary considering that the partitions and equivalence classes are essentially interchangeable.

Comment: '$\sim$' is sometimes caled twiddle just as the times operator ($\times$) may be called `into`.

Comment: You sometimes see the notation $[a]$ for the equivalence class of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! It could also be read as, "the cell containing $a$ is defined as the set of all $x$ in $S$ such that $x$ **relates** to $a$." In particular cases, you would of course replace "$x$~$a$" with the given condition.

Comment: Mathematicians in English are unlikely to use the term "cell." Since terminology is about communication, better to use a term that  mathematicians might understand.

Comment: Really? I've always heard/used cell. Would you say the partition of $S$ where $a\in S$?

Comment: @Michael I just noticed that my textbook to refer to a "cell" of a partition, versus an "equivalence class" of an equivalence relation.

Comment: @justin interesting!

Comment: I've heard "part of a partition," sometimes. @Michael